# Android TextView.setText(" ") stops my app

Tags: android

Each time I try my android very simple code I get this problem 
Unfortunately .apk has stopped .

When I remove uid.setText("txt"), the application runs normally.

My activity code

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            uid.setText("txt");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

My xml file

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"/>
```

Comment: Call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` directly after `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before finding any view  using `findViewById` from Layout of current Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  that is work  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android all the user interface is written in xml. When an activity starts it needs to know which UI xml to display to the user, so when we call setContentView with a layout file, that particular xml is rendered.
The reason for your application to crash is because, you are calling the .setText() method on a textview, but the android activity cannot understand which textview to reference. And PS, you can have multiple UI elements with same ID, but in different files.

So all together call the setContentView() method before referencing any UI element.

Answer (score 1):

Move setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); up.

shown in below code:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        uid.setText("txt");
```